# query without duplicates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query with duplicates. And now I need to build query without duplicates. I'm trying to do it, but my query need long time. My query with duplicates:

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    Clients c 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            iin,
            COUNT(iin) AS countIIN
        FROM
            Clients
        GROUP BY
            iin
        HAVING
            COUNT(iin) > 1
    ) cc
    ON c.IIN = cc.IIN
ORDER BY
    c.last_name DESC
```

I need above anti-query.

Comment: Replace `having count(iin) > 1` to `having count(iin) = 1`.

Comment: What is the schema of the `Clients` table? What is the significance of the `iin` column, what does it mean?

Comment: Thanks all, I fix it with advice of @FelixPamittan.

Comment: I think you are going to miss some clients if `iin` count > 1, should you get the top 1 or just let it go?

Comment: Sorry for being rude but I observed most of the time OPs just want an immediate answers. They don't really bother about exact business requirements. @Eric your question really matters to us but not OP, I guess. :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to find only unique record.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT *, COUNT(IIN) OVER (PARTITION BY IIN) RECORDCOUNT FROM CLIENTS)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RECORDCOUNT =1
```

make sure `*` should be replace in query with required column.

Also if you want to fetch unique record from duplicate list as well then you can choose below query

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT *, RECORD_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IIN ORDER BY IIN) RECORDCOUNT FROM CLIENTS)
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RECORDCOUNT =1
```

Answer (score 0):

To find [duplicates in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-duplicate-rows-using-row-number-partition-by-order-by.aspx) Row_Number() function is best option,

Please check following query

```
WITH [CTE NoDuplicates] AS
(
SELECT
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY iin ORDER BY c.last_name DESC),
  *
FROM Clients
)
DELETE FROM [CTE DUPLICATE] WHERE RN = 1
```